# Debounce method not executed in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

I have the following functions imported in a js file.

```
import {  debounce } from "@/abc/def";
```

The handleAttributes function gets called from the following event listener from the same file.

```
export const attributesHandler = (canvas) => {
  bus.on("attributeChange", (attributes, object) => {
    handleAtrributes({ canvas, attributes, component: object });
  });
};
```

The debounce method is not executed in the handleAtrributes function.

```
const handleAtrributes = async ({ attributes, canvas, component }) => {
    debounce(() => {
      getComponentScreenshot(component, canvas);
    }, 600);
  
};
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but normally `debounce` returns a new function so you wouldn't want it to be called inside an event handler anyways. The function returned by `debounce` should the event handler, e.g. `const handleAttributes = debounce(({canvas, component}) => getComponentScreenshot(component, canvas), 600)`

Comment: Thank you I have made changes kind of like the same and everything is working currently. But I would still like to know why I was not able to access the function.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that reproduces that error?

Comment: My guess is that it wasn't `debounce` that's undefined but something else maybe.

Comment: Thanks man. You are right and now I feel kind of stupid. But I learned how should I not use debounce and thank you for that.